# Why does pregen character Iseph have +11 to acrobatics and +10 to piloting at level 1?

Tags: starfinder, pregenerated-characters

Paizo provides [pregenerated level 1 character stats for iconic character Iseph](https://paizo.com/products/btpy9ukw). Among the stat bonuses listed, it mentions "Acrobatics +11" and "Piloting +10 (1 rank)".

I don't understand how these numbers can be possible. By my calculations, Piloting should be $$4 (\text{DEX}) + 3 (\text{trained class skill}) +  1 (\text{rank}) + 1 (\text{operative's edge}) = 9$$

and Acrobatics should be either

\begin{align}4 (\text{ DEX}) + 3 (\text{ trained class skill}) + 1 (\text{ rank})+{}\\  1 (\text{ operative's edge}) + 3 (\text{ ghost specialization skill focus}) &= 12\end{align}

or $$4 (\text{ DEX}) + 1 (\text{ operative's edge}) + 3 (\text{ ghost specialization skill focus}) = 8$$ depending on whether I put a rank into it or not.

What am I missing?

Comment: Just to be clear: the first sum was a typo or also a mistake?

Comment: Oops, that's a typo. In reality I expected 4 + 3 + 1 + 1 to equal 9. Good observation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You miss Ace Pilot character theme.

It states that Ace Pilot gets pilot as his class skill, but if it's a class skill for 1st level - Ace Pilot gets +1 to their piloting.

So, piloting should be:
4 dex + 3 class skill +1 Ace Pilot +1 Rank + 1 Operative Edge = 10, just as in charsheet.

Specializations says that you gain Skill focus feat and one free rank at every character level in those skills. And, thanks to [ifusaso](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/28326/ifusaso) from comments for pointing that both Operative Edge and Skill Focus are insight bonuses, so they don't stack and largest is used.
Thus, athletics:
4 Dex + 3 class skill + 1 Rank + 3 Skill focus = 11, just as charsheet says.

Comment: I would add that there is another a little more trivial thing the OP was missing in the question: 4+3+1+1 is 9, not 8. That makes up for the *other* point that was missing when getting to 8.

Comment: Nice explanation. I never looked up my character theme because I thought it was just fluff. insight bonuses not stacking is also news to me.